# Toilet smell issue

Tags: bathroom, toilet

I noticed a sickly sweet smell in my bathroom, a friend said it was possibly sewage, and I noticed that when I check my toilet shited very slightly when I messed with it. So on a friend's advice I replaced the wax ring, put it all back and the smell came back... any ideas?

Comment: there are different hight wax rings, which one did you get

Comment: hope you ment shifted!!

Answer (score 1):

When you replaced the wax ring, did you happen to notice the flange hight.

It should be about 1/4 inch above the floor or flat with the floor..

If it is not you need Toilet Flange Extender.

Also you need to seal the toilet perimeter with caulk.

Comment: I used a Harvey no seep ring and the flange is flush with the floor. I did notice that a couple of the tiles butting up to the flange were broken, a small piece the size of a dime missing. Could that be anything? I'm at a loss for what else could be causing this.I also caulked the whole peremiter of the toilet. Could that be anything? I'm at a loss for what else could be causing this.

Comment: @Manakttan just fill those with some